# Error from CALayerArray in tableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, calayer

I've got an app that has been out for sometime, but we are seeing some issues now when running on iOS 5.0 & up. The crash happens when a user selects a cell in a `tableview`. The `tableview` is toggling a checkmark on or off so that the end user can select items from a list to refine a query. Everything worked great from version 3 & 4, but then it just broke when iOS 5 came out.

This is actually an app that I inherited from another developer when I took this job, so there is no telling how deep this problem runs. I did find that if I changed the way he was displaying the checkmark that it fix the problem, but then the checkmark would disappear as soon as I scrolled it off screen in the view.

The console is showing the following error. Any advice would be most appreciated.

```
-[CALayerArray row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796db410

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CALayerArray row]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x796db410'
```

Comment: If you could provide the full stack trace and the code for `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, that would help us figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a typical case of an overreleased object. To debug this kind of problem you could use the allocations instrument with the NSZombie detection enabled.